# How to start/stop wpa_supplicant on default raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I configured wpa_supplicant so I have a wifi connection after boot up. Now I want to stop it for while and start it again. I tried:

```
rpi ~$ sudo ifdown wlan0
ifdown: unknown interface wlan0
```

But `wlan0` exists:

```
rpi ~$ ip addr show dev wlan0
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether b8:27:eb:06:e8:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.10.112/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global wlan0
```

Trying to use *systemd* also fails. `wpa_supplicant.service` is already disabled:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service 
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I have looked at `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/10-wpa_supplicant` but cannot figure out how to use it.

Comment: It's an actual program and you can kill it, although if you are using the system networking stuff there's a good chance something will just start it up again.  You're also running a dhcp client on that interface, and that is a program you can kill or stop (`dhclient` or I think `dhcpcd`; with the former you can use `dhclient -r` to stop it) but the same caveat probably applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a while now I understand how it works. **wpa_supplicant** is managed by `dhcpcd` using a hook. Neither **ifupdown** networking, managed with `/etc/network/interfaces`, is involved nor the **systemd** service. `wpa_supplicant.service` is completely ignored by `dhcpcd` and has no functionality. To stop/start wpa_supplicant you have four possibilies.

If you want to quick stop/start temporary the wifi connection you can just down/up the interface. This will not stop **wpa_supplicant**. It is still running in the background and can respond to other requests. I use `wpa_cli` to control `wpa_supplicant`.

```
rpi ~$ sudo ip link set dev wlan0 down
rpi ~$ wpa_cli ping
PONG
rpi ~$ sudo ip link set dev wlan0 up
```

If you want that **wpa_supplicant** does not do anything to be sure that there are no side effects with wifi you can terminate it completely. To start it again you have to restart **dhcpcd**:

```
rpi ~$ wpa_cli terminate
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'
OK
rpi ~$ wpa_cli ping
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service
```

If you want to disable **wlan0** persistent to be used by **wpa_supplicant** you can add this line to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. It will also do not start wpa_supplicant if there is no other wifi interface available. Otherwise it is started to manage other wifi interfaces.

```
denyinterfaces wlan0
```

If you want to disable **wpa_supplicant** in general you can add this line to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

Comment: This answer states that `wpa_supplicant` is not controlled/managed by (among other things) `systemd`. Based on a simple experiment on my RPi 3B+, RPi OS Lite, `bullseye` host, it seems that the `systemd` service ***may*** now be involved. Running `systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service` yields an output that says `wpa_supplicant` is `loaded`, and `active (running)`.