# Rpi 0 W, wifi no scan results

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w, raspbian-lite

I have this freshly bought Raspberry Pi 0 W.
I created a USB connection between the rpi and my laptop (ubuntu 20.04) and I ssh-ed into the rpi.

The OS on the pi is Raspberry OS Lite.
Using a microSDHC 32GB from SanDisk.

I power the pi from my Galaxy S7 phone charger, has 5V and 2A, it's pretty old. But in this case it also gets power from laptop's USB.

The issue is that I cannot see any wi fi networks when scanning, but my router is 1 meter (3ft) away from my rpi (i do have a 2.4 Ghz network)

Should I consider sending the RPI back to the seller? Or do you see any fix to this?

Here is the output of some commands from which you could get an idea of the situation:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.42.0.164  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
        inet6 fe80::791:86e2:3cb7:26c7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e2:c9:a6:a8:02:37  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 148  bytes 17566 (17.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 109  bytes 15174 (14.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:f3:6a:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17+ #1414 Fri Apr 30 13:16:27 BST 2021 armv6l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/debian_version
10.9
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS    : 697.95
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : 9000c1
Serial      : 0000000014a63f97
Model       : Raspberry Pi Zero W Rev 1.1

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e2:c9:a6:a8:02:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.164/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute usb0
       valid_lft 3118sec preferred_lft 2668sec
```

And here you can see the no results found:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iw dev wlan0 scan
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     No scan results
```

I tried using the wpa_supplicant.conf file but to no success.
I even tried to do a headless wi-fi start but it wouldn't connect to my network. (i couldn't ping it or see it on my router's devices' list)

My router type is a TP Link Archer C64.
It is just an acces point, connected to another router which is the gateway to the internet.

I honestly do not know what to do anymore. Tomorrow I'll receive an OTG adapter and I will connect my keyboard to the pi.
But I think I should have been able to see some networks even when ssh-ed through USB cable.

UPDATE:

Here is the wpa_supplicant.conf that I tried to use before booting up the pi. Password has been changed in order to post here.

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
country=RO
update_config=1
network={
 ssid="Camera2"
 psk="66354632A"
}
```

After booting up, I ssh-ed through USB then I did a wifi scan and no results.
Then I did

```
sudo raspi-config
```

And I set the wi-fi location as Romania. After that I had to reboot.
Then I would no longer be able to ssh through USB and I see on the pi monitor (i have an HDMI plugged into it) "my ip address is 169.254.34.95"

A quick google says this ip is gotten at a failed dhcp.
But the pi is still not on my router's device list.

Probably it tried to get an address from the usb connection once it rebooted.

EDIT 2: I eventually managed to ssh in it using the USB. Here is some output.
Still not seeing any wi-fi. (Remember that this time the location wifi has been set through raspi-config to Romania) and it rebooted.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=RO

network={
    ssid="Camera2"
    psk="246563563A"
}
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iw dev wlan0 scan
```

Comment: Did you try in `raspi-config` under `4 Localisation Options` and then under  `I4 Change Wi-fi Country`  setting a country? Otherwise `rfkill` will disable your WiFi.

Comment: At some point I did that too, but I was trying to connect through wpa_supplicant and I did not do so much scanning. I will try again. So I will ssh into it, do the localisation thing, then scan. Is this order ok?

Comment: Post the contents of /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf (with the SSID and password redacted). There's some stuff that must be in that file. Undo any changes you've made to /etc/network/interfaces as that breaks networking.

Comment: Do you want me to write the wpa_supplicant.conf before booting up the pi? Or after I ssh into it through usb?

Comment: Updated the main topic.

Comment: I wonder if your difficulties are due to using your Pi 0W as a [***USB OTG***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) device?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked this?:

`ifconfig` says `wlan0` is present, but not `RUNNING`, so perhaps check that `wpa-supplicant.conf` was actually created:

```
$ less /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The file should be present, and roughly structured like this:

> ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
> update_config=1
> country=UK
>
> network={
> ssid="YourWiFiSSID"
> psk="YourWiFiPassword"
> }

You can also use `wpa_cli` to verify that `wpa_supplicant` is actually running:

```bash
$ wpa_cli list_networks 

# which should yield something like this iaw my system, where Mesh01 is the SSID of my wifi: 

Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'
network id / ssid / bssid / flags
0   Mesh01  any
```

---

***Epilog:**
However it now occurs to me, 18 months later, that the issue you may be facing is that by connecting your Pi 0W to your Ubuntu via USB you are using it as a [USB On-the-Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) device. *This changes everything!* [This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98017/83790) speaks to that difference, and may help sort the issues associated with using the wifi interface as you seem to be trying to do.*

Comment: In the main post, down at EDIT 2, I have managed to ssh in pi while having a supplicant. There I did a cat command and I showed it in a code snippet. Unfortunatelly,  I got no results from scanning. Perhaps I should have checked the output of ifconfig again? As you can see, the supplicant is there.

Comment: So how do we make sure it gets RUNNING?

Comment: @Gauthier: That's actually a good question. I've addressed it with an edit to my answer, but I wish you'd post it as a new question. I *thought* I knew the **definitive** answer, but when I checked an [earlier Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85599/how-to-start-stop-wpa-supplicant-on-default-raspbian) that I've relied upon, it seems that *things have been changed*!